# Hadith of Allah reciting Qur'an before creation?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is this hadith authentic?

> Narrated AbuHurayrah
>
> Allah's Messenger (peace be upon him) said, "A thousand years before
>   creating the heavens and the Earth, Allah RECITED Ta-Ha and Ya-Sin,
>   and when the angels HEARD the recitation they said, 'Happy are the
>   people to whom this comes down, happy are the minds which carry this,
>   and happy are the tongues which utter this." Darimi transmitted it
>   (Tirmidhi Hadith, 660-

Answer (score 1):

This hadith indeed is part of the [sunan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunan_al-Darimi) of [ad-Darimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Darimi) where you will find it in the:
"Chapter about the virtues of the Quran/ Chapter of about the virtues of surat Ya-Sin."

> [رقم الحديث: 3319](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?hflag=1&bk_no=137&pid=66717)
>   (حديث مرفوع) حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ الْمُنْذِرِ ، حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ الْمُهَاجِرِ بْنِ الْمِسْمَارِ ، عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ حَفْصِ بْنِ ذَكْوَانَ ، عَنْ مَوْلَى الْحُرَقَةِ ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ، قَالَ : قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " إِنَّ اللَّهَ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالَى قَرَأَ طه ، وَيس قَبْلَ أَنْ يَخْلُقَ السَّمَوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضَ بِأَلْفِ عَامٍ ، فَلَمَّا سَمِعَتْ الْمَلَائِكَةُ الْقُرْآنَ ، قَالَتْ : طُوبَى لِأُمَّةٍ يَنْزِلُ هَذَا عَلَيْهَا ، وَطُوبَى لِأَجْوَافٍ تَحْمِلُ هَذَا ، وَطُوبَى لِأَلْسِنَةٍ تَتَكَلَّمُ بِهَذَا " .

The narrator chain is as follows:
Ibrahim ibn al-Mundhir (trustworthy, among the teachers of al-Bukhari etc.) from
Ibrahim ibn al-Muhajir ibn al-Mismar (monkar al-hadith/rejected or denounced for fabrication?) from
'Omar ibn Hafs ibn Dhakwan (matrook al-Hadith/rejected) from
al-Hurqah (trustworthy) from
abu Hurairah (See also [the fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/90186) posted by Hamza Islam).

So as you see we have two narrators of this chain are very weak, and note they have narrated one from the other:

Ibn Kathir in his [tafsir of surat Ta-Ha](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1129&idto=1129&bk_no=49&ID=1151) has also quoted the same hadith and added:

> هذا حديث غريب ، وفيه نكارة ، وإبراهيم بن مهاجر وشيخه تكلم فيهما .

This could be translated as follows: "This is a strange hadith and it has a terrible content (or is "terrible" or has terrible issues) and Ibrahim ibn Muhajir and his teacher are among those whom people have spoke about (meaning qualified them as weak or about their trustworthiness, maybe one could also say they were black marked by scholars)"

The hadith therefore has terrible weaknesses and can't be considered as authentic.

---

The hadith was also commented by Mulla ['Ali al-Qari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_al-Qari) in his commentary on [Meshkat al-Massabyh](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=79&ID=108&idfrom=4205&idto=4432&bookid=79&startno=39).